# Remove all keys except current one in foreach, javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

`order.get_orderlines()` is an array of three objects.

I want to call the **print_xml** function everytime I loop on an orderline where `product.is_gift_product == true`,  but I also want to clean the array before.

Each time, I want to remove all other rows except the one I'm looping on.

I tried to remove all key on which I'm looping where `product.is_gift_product != true`, and when I loop on a orderline on which `product.is_gift_product == true`, to remove everything after, but this way I'm not printing the same tickets number as of the number of products marked as gift.

```
// START GIFT PRODUCT MANAGEMENT
var order_saved = order;
order.get_orderlines().forEach( function (orderline, i) {
    if (orderline.product.is_gift_product != true) {
        order.get_orderlines().splice(i, 1);
        order_saved = order;
    } else {
        order.get_orderlines().splice(i, 9e9);
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.print_xml_gift(order, 'XmlGiftReceipt');
            order._printed = true;
        }, 2000);
    }
});
// END GIFT PRODUCT MANAGEMENT
```

Comment: What is this construct? Splice till end? `order.get_orderlines().splice(i, 9e9);`

Comment: Yes, i tried it, but i wasn't looking to the good function to achieve what i wanted to :/ but yes, it splice till end (till 9e9 ... But i'll never have that much rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try chaining a `.filter(orderLine => orderLine.product.is_gift_product)` before calling your forEach.

Answer (score 0):

you should filter all elements to take a gift products.

During filtering, you can call for print of them.

```
const order_saved = order.get_orderlines().filter(orderline => 
  orderline.product.is_gift_product).forEach(() => {
    setTimeout(function(){
      self.print_xml_gift(order, 'XmlGiftReceipt');
      order._printed = true;
    }, 2000);
});
```

I'm not sure if you need this timeout

Comment: Also I believe you have a closure issue here